# Can nettype be used to define struct in System Verilog?

Tags: system-verilog

Can `nettype` be used to define struct in SystemVerilog language?

I am getting failure in defining so, can anybody tell me?

Comment: Please show your code with the error message(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `nettype` cannot be used as a member of a `struct`. Only other data types can be used as struct members. A `nettype` is a kind of signal that can have a data type, including a `struct`, but a `nettype` itself is not a data type.